# Is a Standalone SharePoint 2010 Server Good Enough as a Test Environment for Production SharePoint Farm

Tags: 2010, development, sharepoint-server, testing, standalone

I have inherited SharePoint 2010 at work and would like to test some features we are not utilizing.

I would like a testing environment for SP but being limited on resources, I want to set this up on a single Desktop. Would a Standalone server work or are there too many differences (when it comes to problems and troubleshooting)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their are two options for test farm either stand alone or single server farm(complete).

**Stand Alone:**

The standalone installation type installs SharePoint using the Local Service and Network Service accounts and a SQL Express instance. It is not a farm and has limitations such as:

- Standalone is not a SharePoint farm
- Cannot join additional servers (since it's not a farm)
- Limited database size due to using SQL Express
- Cannot provision the User Profile Synchronization service (since the
  Local Service account cannot connect to Active Directory)
- While users in a domain can connect and authenticate to sites in a
  standalone installation,
- you will find that you cannot use the People Picker to get users from
  AD, again because Local Service cannot contact AD
- All services in the farm are set up and configured on the server, not
  necessarily configured the way you want.
- Database names are all default names that include GUIDs which some
  find ugly (and hard to type)

**Single Server**

- With the complete/server farm option,
- you can create an entire SharePoint farm with any configuration you
  want.
- You can install an instance of SQL Server on the same server if you
  want a single-server farm.
- You can have multiple servers and you can configure or not configure
  any available server.
- Integration with AD works, and in general a farm is more widely 
  supported as most specialists work with farms and not standalone 
  installations.

Comment: I would go with single server version since it allows you to expand the farm if needed. However, if possible you should have a setup as close to production as possible because dealing with multiple servers can sometimes be tricky. You can choose to have dev and test in that scenario

Comment: Yeah thanks Waqas and onzur. I forgot that I technically do not need multiple servers and I can just bundle everything up in one which is probably what I am going to do. As I said, I am sadly limited to resources and I tend to choose for what I request. Thanks guys.